# how to make angular $filter to filter a case sensitive string comparators

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have been trying to make the filter in angular controller which is case sensitive while filtering the array.

My data is as below:

```
var stoneArr = 
[
    {
        "stone_name": "Diamond",
        "id": 16
    },
    {
        "stone_name": "Ruby",
        "id": 17
    },
    {
        "stone_name": "Sapphire",
        "id": 18
    },
    {
        "stone_name": "Emerald",
        "id": 19
    }
];
```

My HTML input is as below:

```
<input type="text" name="stone_name" class="form-control" id="stone_name"
ng-model="propertyName" maxlength="15" required>
```

My filter in controller is:

```
var stoneObj = $filter('filter')(stoneArr, {stone_name:$scope.propertyName}, true);
```

Here the trap is that when i enter "diamond" in input field

```
$scope.propertyName = "diamond";
```

the filter doesn't match this string with the "Diamond".

I don't want to remove the exact match condition (true) from the equation as shown below:

```
var stoneObj = $filter('filter')(stoneArr, {stone_name:$scope.propertyName}); //This won't work for me
```

This won't work for me, because i want to match the exact string to filter the data. And the data will have unique "stone_name" values. Also i don't want to use any loops since the array length will go above 1000+. Is there anyway i can achieve this?

Comment: Internally the $filter does a loop. I would do a single function with that compare, or to create another specific filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a match function to get case insensitive match:

```
var stoneObj = $filter('filter')(stoneArr, function (item) {
    return item.stone_name.toLowerCase() == $scope.propertyName.toLowerCase();
},true);
```